# Problems building cwac-touchlist android project

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to build the cwac-touchlist project following the steps in the README from https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist. The first step is to build the toplevel project with **ant parcel**, but the **parcel** target does not exist in the project!

Has anyone ran into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies -- those were obsolete build instructions. The top-level and `demo/` sub-project are linked via the Android library project system. If you import the top-level and the `demo/` sub-project each into Eclipse, they should build. Or, run `ant clean debug install` from the `demo/` subdirectory to build and install via the command line.